# UIimagepickercontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIimagepickercontroller to browse or take a photo and display it on a subview.

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {

    secondView1 = [[secondView alloc] 
               initWithNibName:@"secondView"
               bundle:nil];
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];    
    [self.view addSubview:secondView1.view];
}
```

This works fine for SourceTypeSavedPhotoAlbum, but if I use camera, the secondview1.view does not show. Instead it only shows the original view.

This is my delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    secondView1.imageView.image = [info
    objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you using Simulator or device? If device, does it have camera?

Comment: On device. Have camera. I can take a photo then confirm 'use'. After that, the uiimagepickercontroller is dismissed, but return to the original view, not secondview1.view.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that I should do:

```
secondView1 = [[secondView alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"secondView"
    bundle:nil];
self.view addSubview:secondView1.view];
```

in the delegate function.

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, the `addsubview` could be called before the image picker finishes picking an image. Now understand better about how the code flows and the delegate functions.